# Android GoogleMaps Activity with Actionbar

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar, google-maps-api-2

I'm trying to stick an ActionBar over my GoogleMaps activity. I've been referring to [this doc](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html) and I do have the appropriate Actionbar library in my MapsActivity. I'm new to android development so am I going about this wrong? My maps activity header looks like this:

```
public class MapsActivity extends ActionBarActivity
```

The onCreate code is:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    setUpMap();
}
```

When I add the following code

```
getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

I receive the following error for that line:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{login.package.comet.samplelogin/login.package.comet.halp.MapsActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

I appreciate any help you have to offer!

Answer (score 0):

Try using `getSupportActionBar()` instead of `getActionBar()`. [`ActionBarActivity`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBarActivity.html) is a support Activity.

Answer (score 0):

I normally use something like `getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);` and it works :)